# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar due to LinkageError

Tags: sonarqube

I was following this reference to setup and run code analysis on my localhost mac.
https://techblost.com/how-to-setup-sonarqube-locally-on-mac/

However, when I run the command.

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=My-Service \
  -Dsonar.projectName='My Service' \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.token=sqp_xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I encountered the following failure,  could anyone help diagnose or shed some light?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar[m [1m(default-cli)[m on project [36mmy_service[m: [1;31mExecution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger: when selecting method 'org.slf4j.spi.LoggingEventBuilder org.slf4j.Logger.makeLoggingEventBuilder(org.slf4j.event.Level)' the class loader org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm @16b4a017 for super interface org.slf4j.Logger, and the class loader org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader @5df47fb5 of the selected method's class, ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger have different Class objects for the type org.slf4j.spi.LoggingEventBuilder used in the signature (org.slf4j.Logger is in unnamed module of loader org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm @16b4a017, parent loader 'app'; ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger is in unnamed module of loader org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader @5df47fb5, parent loader org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm @15f23508)[m
[ERROR] [1;31m-----------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] [1;31mrealm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184[m
[ERROR] [1;31mstrategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy[m
[ERROR] [1;31murls[0] = file:/Users/myuser/Development/Maven/Repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.1.2184/sonar-maven-plugin-3.9.1.2184.jar[m
[ERROR] [1;31murls[1] = file:/Users/myuser/Development/Maven/Repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar[m
[ERROR] [1;31murls[2] = file:/Users/myuser/Development/Maven/Repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar[m
[ERROR] [1;31murls[3] = file:/Users/myuser/Development/Maven/Repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar[m
[ERROR] [1;31murls[4] = file:/Users/myuser/Development/Maven/Repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.2.588/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.2.588.jar[m
[ERROR] [1;31murls[5] = file:/Users/myuser/Development/Maven/Repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar[m
[ERROR] [1;31mNumber of foreign imports: 1[m
[ERROR] [1;31mimport: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]][m
[ERROR] [1;31m[m
[ERROR] [1;31m-----------------------------------------------------[
```

Thanks!

I tried many times but there was no luck.